# non localized images not recognized in localized xib files

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, interface-builder, xib

I localized and xib files to two languages , the xib contains a UIImageView and UIButtons that I set the value of their image property for the Interface Builder, when i use localized images to set these properties everything works ok and the images appear on run time , but when i use non localized image the images just don't show and i get this on the log

**"Could not load the "greenBackgroundImage.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "(null)"**

I don't want to end up localizing all my images even if I'm using the same image for both languages.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your non-localized images don't end up in your bundle. Have a look in your build settings (select your project > select target > Build Phases > expand section Copy Bundle Resources). If greenBackgroundImage.png isn't listed there, just add it.